# enabling checkbox elements dynamically using java script

Tags: javascript

I have below HTML code

```
<input class="user_roles" type="checkbox" id="Administrator" />
<input class="user_roles" type="checkbox" id="Installer" /> 
<input class="user_roles" type="checkbox" id="Starter" />

<input type="hidden" class="peter" id="peter_Administrator" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" class="peter" id="peter_Installer" value="0" /> 
<input type="hidden" class="peter" id="peter_Starter" value="2" />
```

I have above HTML file generated dynamically and sent to browser. In browser I have to write
a java script function which reads the hidden values and sets the check box enabled or disabled for that user. If value is 1 then check box should be enabled and grayed out i.e., disabled i.e., user cannot change it. If value is 0 check box user can enable it, and if value is 2 users can enable/disable it, but color should be yellow.

Below I want to add a note that yellow stands for temporary roles, grayed are for permanent roles.

I am new to java script. How best we can do this using DOM object model API's. I am not supposed to use any java script frameworks. I have to simple java script DOM

Request your help. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: I think you should start reading up on JavaScript. You are essentially asking us to do the job for you. See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Instead show your efforts and where you got stuck with some undesired behaviour.

Comment: Normally we are open to answer, but this is a perfect use case to ask ChatGPT. You can refine your question regarding your use case if the answer does not fit your needs. Mayby try that first. If you still struggle come back here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use JavaScript in this case. You already have information on the back-end it looks like.

I don't understand exactly how the checkboxes should be styled. An input element has an attribute called `disabled`, so instead of creating that hidden input element you can just set that attribute.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Administrator" disabled />
```

You can also make the checkbox checked by setting the checked attribute:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Administrator" checked />
```

And these two attributes can then be combined. And you can also style the checkboxes accordingly with [the input Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#input_pseudo-classes). Here just some examples:

```css
input:disabled {
  border: thin solid yellow;
}

input:enabled {
  border: thin solid green;
}

input:checked {
  border: thin solid red;
}
```